# SQL start ROW_NUMBER() at 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this line of code:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END) AS SortOrder
```

but this starts at 1..... How do I get it to start at 0?

I've tried `ROW_NUMBER() - 1` but that didn't work. I also tried `1 - ROW_NUMBER()` but that gives me 0 then -1.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END) - 1 AS SortOrder`

Answer (score 16):

You can try `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END) - 1 AS SortOrder`

Answer (score 8):

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [ColumnName]) - 1 AS SortOrder from        temp_table
```